# Database design for User and Developer

Tags: database

I want to create a web service which has entities - user and developer.

Developer may or may not be a user (I expect him to be a user in most cases). He can use a web API to create his applications on top of my web service. Example - Facebook allows us to create apps on developer.facebook.com, where we log in using our FB account.

My query is - should I create separate tables for User and Developer? User has some attributes which a typical developer need not have. And developer sees certain features which a typical user will not see.

Tradeoff is - For 2 separate tables there will be redundant data, but I expect a very few developers compared to users.

For same table - there will be redundant attributes.

What will be the best design for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how different your generic users will be from your developers. What extra fields would you need for a developer? If none, then the answer is simple: one table for both.
You might even think about having some sort of inheritance relationship with a developer table only having the extra fields plus a user_id.

What sorts of extra fields are you thinking you may have?

Answer (score 0):

If neither inherit entirely from the other then it makes sense to use 2 separate tables. Sure, they may have some similar attributes but I gather you'll never really use a User/Developer interchangeably.

If you're really worried about redundancy the alternative would be to automatically sign any Developer up as a User but with additional attributes which would be stored in their associated record in the Developer table.

In short, if the entities really are 100% separate and it makes sense for a Developer to have to sign up once as a Dev and another time as a User (with no link between the accounts) then they probably belong in 2 separate tables. But if the Developer can be viewed as a kind of "super-user" with extended attributes, then I'd store all base records in the Users table with the addition Developer attributes in a table of their own (the second scenario sounds more likely to me).